# Android Parse.com Push Notifications Application Crashes on Start

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-manifest

I followed the tutorial on parse.com to push notifications. But my application is crashing on start. I think the error is in the Manifest file.

This is my code:

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission  android:name="com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"
        />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddCustomer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_customer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddCustomerDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_customer_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".notificationactivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notificationactivity" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the onCreate method of the main activity:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPass);
        // Enable Local Datastore.

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "QKpM7ar7aWwrbEeTcrSGJ5bDnLMCUtc1kCr26Enl", "MCBdIQ6Y0dTsIoahzJ44UfR1zHZPJMQPwiETwj47");


    }
```

Could you please help me. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); stuff in extends Application

Answer (score 0):

I tried calling `MyApplication` class and extended it to Application that resolved my problem.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Please do not forget to declare `MyApplication` class in android manifest

`<application android:name=".MyApplication" />`